# How to export private key with simple s2k in GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg, private-key

I am trying to export a secret key out of GPG for testing purpose and to facilitate the decryption of the private key, I'd like to export it with a simple s2k (s2k-mode 0) but all my attempt seem to fail. Here's how I proceed:

First export the key with GPG

```
$ gpg --export-secret-key --rfc4880bis --s2k-mode 0 --output privkey.bin D753C0F6
gpg: WARNING: using experimental features from RFC4880bis!
gpg: Note: simple S2K mode (0) is strongly discouraged
```

And then parse it with Julia with a code of my own

```
julia> bin2packet("privkey.bin")[1]
Secret-Key Packet
 Length : 162, partial : false
 ----------------
  Version : 4, Time : 2019-02-13T17:37:37
 Algorithm : ECDSA public key algorithm [FIPS186] using scep256k1
 scep256k1 Point(,):
f05314566c9bfc8d8cf463a7a01e7735245d588a60dd874f09a9636620abb314,
6bda245d43cbbe019ab1ad74316d675dd858cdd776820969bcc21bbccbd3a661
 Specifics : Any[0xfe, "AES with 128-bit key [AES]", Any[3, "SHA1", "d6c9d217d64fb4ad", 31457296], "d0c6dd2e6320d5c4be5414161a7ef660806c531ff0c2a8e762a7b7898ce5e96c78708461c0f6777cc4c20a1ae9cd5f076c62120291d96306101d5e0e0386bac3b285fe0f8747"]
```

Be it with s2k-mode option set or not, I do get the same output, with an s2k specifier set to 3 (Iterate and Salt) `[3, "SHA1", "d6c9d217d64fb4ad", 31457296]` for mode, hash algorithm, salt and bit count respectively.

First of all, am I exporting the key correctly with GnuPG ?
Is GPG forcing s2k-mode 3 in some way and can it by bypassed?

GPG version for the record

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.12
libgcrypt 1.8.4
```

Comment: I made my life easier by simply removing key encryption, thanks to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677303/gnupg-private-key-can-be-exported-without-password). I'm still curious to see how to change s2k mode